# What does a proof that Co-NP =P entail for the NP versus Co-NP question

Tags: complexity-theory

What I wonder is what exactly would it entail. Would it,for instance imply that P=NP or would there be different consequences,I haven't found any assorted consequences so far in my research.
Thank You,
Akash

Answer (score 5):

$\text{P}=\text{co-NP}$ implies that $\text{co-P}=\text{co-(co-NP)}=\text{NP}$.  But 
$\text{co-P}=\text{P}$: you can just swap the accept and reject states of a deterministic Turing machine to complement the language that it decides.